# Logic on a Pandas Dataframe with a string

Tags: python, pandas, logic

This should be a really easy one, but I can't figure it out::
I have a dataframe, df, and it has two string values, "normal" and "odd". 
I'd like to find out how many are in either catagory::

```
type(bro_df)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

print(len(bro_df))
2000000

type(bro_df['label'])
pandas.core.series.Series

print(len(bro_df['label'] == 'normal'))
2000000

print(len(bro_df['label'] == 'odd'))
2000000
```

What's going on??!?!

Thanks, 
Nic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`len(bro_df['label'] == 'odd')` is the length of the boolean series of `True` and `False`. If you want the number of rows with those values:

```
(bro_df['label'] == 'odd').sum()
```

Or better yet

```
bro_df.label.value_counts()
```

Comment: Yeah, these both work a treat, and can be applied to my/ones given circumstances. :-) Thanks!!